# How to send e-mail to registered email id's from our webpage?

Tags: php, html, email

I've created one webpage using html and php. In that I need to register some new users email id to send mail from my webpage.. I've created all that forms successfully but when I click the submit button it'll only echo the success page and does not send any mails to subscribers id...

Form code:

```
<div id="mesaj"></div>
                    <form id="subscribe" method="post" action="php/subscribe.php" name="subscribe">
                        <input type="text" id="semail" name="YourEmail" placeholder="Subscribe to our email list" />


                        <input type="submit" id="ssubmit" name="subscribe" value="SUBSCRIBE" class="orange" />
                    </form>
</div>
```

Php coding:

```css
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
 return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$email    = $_POST['email'];
if(trim($email) == '') {
 echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
 exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
 echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You have entered an invalid e-mail address. Please try again.</div>';
 exit();
}

// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";


$address = "abc@gmail.com";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'New email subscriber ' . $email . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "New email subscriber: $email";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

 // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

 echo "<fieldset>";
 echo "<div id='success_page'>";
 echo "<h1>Email registered Successfully.</h1>";
 echo "<p>Thank you! We will contact you as soon as possible!</p>";
 echo "</div>";
 echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

 echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Help me to do this...

Thanks in advance,
Sandra

Comment: Have you checked the mail logs on the server?

Comment: change headers for html, as you are using html in your email body

Comment: How to check it on server?

Comment: @AngelcakeSandra have you tried in localhost ? try with the server

Comment: I've tried in local host only not in the server..

Comment: @AngelcakeSandra can't send mail in localhost, that maybe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this recently and instead of using the variable $address in the mail() function, when I used the actual string address, it worked.

To use the variable, you need to make sure its wrapped in quotes like

```
$address = "someone@email.com"
```

Subtle difference but tricky

Comment: I'll use the same line `$address = "abc@gmail.com";`

Comment: @AngelcakeSandra how did it go?